# How to stop Javascript alert box from popping up on each page load?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery, currency, select

I've been trying to create a popup for the Currency Selector on Magento. With some help I finally got this to working but it pops up on each page load.

Maybe someone knowledgeable in javascript can see how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
<?php if ($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
    <div class="form-currency">
        <select class="dropdown" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="currency-selector"
                id="currency-selector">
            <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $code => $name): ?>
                <option class="label" value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($code) ?>"
                    <?php if ($code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                        selected="selected"
                    <?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $name ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var currency = document.getElementById('currency-selector');
        var showMessage = sessionStorage.showMessage;
        if (showMessage) {
            sweetAlert('<?php echo $this->__('During checkout all charges will be in US dollar') ?>');
            sessionStorage.showMessage = false;
        }
        currency.addEventListener('change', function () {
            sessionStorage.showMessage = true;
            window.location.href = currency.value;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think you should try cookies.
>
> try to set cookie onLoad and check for the existence of it on reLoad.

```
 function setCookie(key, value) {           

        document.cookie = key + '=' + value;
    }

    function getCookie(key) {
        var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
    }

    function delete_cookie(name) {
      document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Will here's how I ended up getting it to work. I used SweetAlert Javascript.

Here the complete working code in case someone wants to try it.

```
<?php 
$country = file_get_contents("http://ip2c.org/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");
if(trim($country) !== "1;US;USA;United States"): ?>
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-currency">
    <select class="dropdown" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="currency-selector" id="currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $code => $name): ?>
        <option class="label" value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($code)?>"
            <?php if($code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $name ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var currency = document.getElementById('currency-selector');
var showMessage = sessionStorage.showMessage;
if (showMessage) {
  sweetAlert({
    title: "<?php echo $this->__('About Our Currency Conversion') ?>", 
    text: "<?php echo $this->__('This is for our Internation customers to see how much something cost in their currency. It\'s updated daily with the latest rates from webservicex.net. Please Note: During the last step in checkout you will be charged in US Dollars.') ?>", 
    type: "success"
});
  delete sessionStorage.showMessage;
}
currency.addEventListener('change', function() {
  sessionStorage.showMessage = true;
  window.location.href = currency.value;
});
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```